# Angular. Data cannot be loaded into ngOnInit

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, http

I need to get the date of the user and posts on the main page, but method ngOnInit puts everything in undefined. The flags on the true do not change. All boolean fields has false in html files. I can't get user and post data in json. It shows me 401 http error.

The same get requests through Postman are successful, I get the user and posts. But in my web-interface the main page is empty. By the way, the getToken method returns the token correctly.

## **User service**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";


const USER_API = 'http://localhost:8080/api/user/';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getUserById(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(USER_API + id);
  }

  getCurrentUser(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(USER_API);
  }

  updateUser(user: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(USER_API + 'update', user);
  }
}
```

## **Post service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Post} from "../models/Post";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
const POST_API = 'http://localhost:8080/api/post/';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PostService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  createPost(post: Post): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(POST_API + 'create', post);
  }

  getAllPosts(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(POST_API + 'all');
  }

  getPostForCurrentUser(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(POST_API + 'user/posts');
  }

  deletePost(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(POST_API + id + '/delete', null);
  }

  likePost(id: number, username: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(POST_API + id + '/' + username + '/like', null);
  }
}
```

**Token storage**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

const TOKEN_KEY = 'auth-token';
const USER_KEY = 'auth-user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TokenStorageService {

  constructor() {
  }

  public saveToken(token: string): void {
    window.sessionStorage.removeItem(TOKEN_KEY);
    window.sessionStorage.setItem(TOKEN_KEY, token);
  }

  public getToken(): string {
    return sessionStorage.getItem(TOKEN_KEY)!;
  }

  public saveUser(user): void {
    window.sessionStorage.removeItem(USER_KEY);
    window.sessionStorage.setItem(USER_KEY, JSON.stringify(user));
  }

  public getUser(): any {
    return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(USER_KEY)!);
  }

  logOut(): void {
    window.sessionStorage.clear();
    window.location.reload();
  }
}
```

Auth interceptor service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest} from "@angular/common/http";
import {TokenStorageService} from "../service/token-storage.service";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";

const TOKEN_HEADER_KEY = 'Authorization';

@Injectable(
  {
    providedIn: 'root'
  }
)
export class AuthInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor{

  constructor(private tokenService: TokenStorageService) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let authRequest = req;
    const token = this.tokenService.getToken();
    if (token) {
      authRequest = req.clone({headers: req.headers.set(TOKEN_HEADER_KEY, token)});
    }

    return next.handle(authRequest);
  }

}

export const authInterceptorProviders = [
  {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptorService, multi: true}
]
```

## **Navigation component (this is navigation panel on my Web-site)**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {User} from "../../models/User";
import {TokenStorageService} from "../../service/token-storage.service";
import {UserService} from "../../service/user.service";
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navigation',
  templateUrl: './navigation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navigation.component.css']
})
export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit {

  isLoggedIn = false;
  isDataLoaded = false;
  user: User;

  constructor(private tokenService: TokenStorageService,
              private userService: UserService,
              private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isLoggedIn = !!this.tokenService.getToken();

    if(this.isLoggedIn) {
      this.userService.getCurrentUser()
        .subscribe((response : any) => {
          this.user = response.data;
          this.isDataLoaded = true;
        })
    }
  }

  logout(): void {
    this.tokenService.logOut();
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }

}
```

## **Index component (this is main page)**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Post} from "../../models/Post";
import {User} from "../../models/User";
import {PostService} from "../../service/post.service";
import {UserService} from "../../service/user.service";
import {CommentService} from "../../service/comment.service";
import {NotificationService} from "../../service/notification.service";
import {ImageUploadService} from "../../service/image-upload.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-index',
  templateUrl: './index.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./index.component.css']
})
export class IndexComponent implements OnInit {

  isPostsLoaded = false;
  posts: Post[];
  isUserDataLoaded = false;
  user: User;


  constructor(private postService: PostService,
              private userService: UserService,
              private commentService: CommentService,
              private notificationService: NotificationService,
              private imageService: ImageUploadService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getCurrentUser()
      .subscribe((response : any) => {
        this.user = response.data;
        this.isUserDataLoaded = true;
        console.log(response.data);
      });

    this.postService.getAllPosts()
      .subscribe((response: any) => {
        this.posts = response.data;
        this.getImagesToPosts(this.posts);
        this.getCommentsToPosts(this.posts);
        this.isPostsLoaded = true;
        console.log(response.data);
      });

  }
```

I checked the correspondence of the user request fields from the client to the server, all fields match. But still I can't get the user.

Comment: The 401 error is pretty straight forward. Check your login process and the interception/injection of the token. Either you are not using a valid token, or you are setting invalid headers, therefore your server rejects the request with a 401. Check if your authorization header needs to add the auth type. For my oauth2 auth I am adding the token like this: request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        });

Comment: I use token from method "getToken". In debug I see token is true.  But ok, I'll try to put him manually.

Comment: By the way, flag "isLoggedIn" in NavigationComponent changes to true, it seems token in head "Authorization" is true.